# How to prevent Apache pig from outputting empty files?

Tags: apache-pig

I have a pig script that reads data from a directory on HDFS. The data are stored as avro files. The file structure looks like:

```
DIR--
   --Subdir1
   --Subdir2
   --Subdir3
   --Subdir4
```

In the pig script I am simply doing a load, filter and store. It looks like:

```
items = LOAD path USING AvroStorage()
items = FILTER items BY some property
STORE items into outputDirectory using AvroStorage()
```

The problem right now is that pig is outputting many empty files in the output directory. I am wondering if there's a way to remove those files? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For pig version 0.13 and later, you can set pig.output.lazy=true to avoid creating empty files.  (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-3299)

Comment: Thanks! Can you clarify where do I set this? Do I set it in the pig script or somewhere else?

Comment: You can set in various places.  One way would be to call "set pig.output.lazy true;" in your pig script